# Can i use Paypal API without having a merchant account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am a noob in paypal and i have been struggling on how to use paypal api using sandbox. Then i realize maybe i can't use the API because i dont have a merchant account.

What i want to do is make my paypal unhosted buttons secure in sandbox. When using unhosted buttons in sandbox, the email of the merchant is exposed, including the price for the payment etc.. So i want to prevent that from  being exposed. I can't use hosted buttons because it won't let me customize the price.

I have searched about how to make my buttons secure and then i found out about API and also paypal IPN. But i seem to get lost on the instructions. Probably because my access are limited because i dont have a real merchant account?

So is it necessary to have myself a merchant account for paypal to access the API and make my buttons secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember (or find) specifically where I read this, but I'm quite sure you need to have a merchant/business account in order to use paypal's more advanced functions. For secure buttons, I'm 99% sure you need one. 
The account is free, so there's little reason not to (yes, I know they take 30 cents per transaction + 2.6%), but the long-term peace of mind is worth it (for me at least).

Answer (score 0):

In sandbox you can make any type of account (personal/business). PayPal will not charge you for a sandbox account as sandbox is used only for testing purpose. Please find below the link to create sandbox account:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Once you create the sandbox account to create a button follow this link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/

You can create a hosted button (easiest to do and safest) or if you want you can create an encrypted button also.